How to set background color to transparent with Phaser 3
Trouble
I added two Text objects to a scene.
But for the latter one, I couldn't set background color to transparent.
Can anyone help me?
Here is the screenshot.


What I tried
I want the Text objects to have transparent background.
I have tried to set backgroundColor like:
this.scene.add.text(0, 0, "hoge", {
  backgroundColor: "rgb(255 255 255 / 0.5)",
});

but it doesn't work.


Source Code

selected-tile-display.ts

This Text object looks good. It has transparent background.
    this.text = (() => {
      const text = this.scene.add.text(0, 0, "x: -, y: -", {
        padding: {
          y: 50 / this.scene.cameras.main.zoom,
        },
        align: "center",
        fixedWidth: containerWidth,
        fixedHeight: containerHeight,
        fontSize: `${100 / this.scene.cameras.main.zoom}px`,
        lineSpacing: 0,
      });

      return text;
    })();


selected-character-display.ts

This Text looks bad. It has black background.
    this.text = (() => {
      const text = this.scene.add.text(0, 0, [
        "a10a",
        "VIT: 0",
      ], {
        fixedWidth: containerWidth,
        fixedHeight: containerHeight,
        fontSize: `${100 / this.scene.cameras.main.zoom}px`,
      });

      return text;
    })();


Minimal Reproducable Example
I created minimal reproducable example.
I found that type: CANVAS option in new PhaserGame and this.load.image does something.
I could make text background transparent when I commented out those lines.
But I do not want to do this because I need to load images and it comes other errors if I change type: CANVAS option.
+ app/
  + _components/
  |  + game/
  |     + scenes/
  |     |   + main-scene/
  |     |       + index.ts
  |     |
  |     + index.tsx
  |
  + globals.css
  + layout.tsx
  + page.tsx


_components/game/index.tsx

"use client";

import { CANVAS, Game as PhaserGame, Scale } from "phaser";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { MainScene } from "./scenes/main-scene";

export function Game() {
  const game = useRef<Phaser.Game | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (game.current === null) {
      game.current = new PhaserGame({
        parent: "game-container",
        // If AUTO, it doesn't work on smartphone browser
        type: CANVAS,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        scale: {
          mode: Scale.ScaleModes.FIT,
        },
        backgroundColor: "#028af8",
        scene: [
          MainScene,
        ],
      });
    }

    return () => {
      if (game.current) {
        game.current.destroy(true);
        
        if (game.current !== null) {
          game.current = null;
        }
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="game-container"></div>
  );
}

export default Game;


_components/game/scenes/main-scene/index.ts

import { Scene } from "phaser";

export class MainScene extends Scene {
  constructor () {
    super("MainScene");
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.image("tiles", "assets/tiles.1.png");
  }

  create () {
    this.add.text(0, 0, "Text 1", {
      fontSize: `10px`,
    });

    this.add.text(0, 20, "Text 2", {
      fontSize: `10px`,
    });
  }
}

GitHub
(clone stackoverflow/questions/78791454 branch and run npm run dev to reproduce)


It depends on environment
I found that it happens only in Chrome browser.

Reproducable

Chrome (126.0.6478.183) in MacOS (14.5)


Not Reproducable

Safari (17.5) in MacOS (14.5)
Chrome (127.0.6533.56) in iOS (17.5.1)
Safari in iOS (17.5.1)




This shouldn't happen, can you provide a minimal reproducable example? Because if you don't set a backgroundColor for the text GameObject, there shouldn't not be any color, as far as I know. May be it is some sideeffects, with other code

@winner_joiner I added Minimal Reproducable Example section to question's body. I still need your help. Thank you.

First of all, I must say: Great Question and incredible summary and analysis.

I did some testing, and noticed that it might have to do with react/nextjs and/or issue with cleaning up  the canvas . Since your phaser code works in a non React and basic React page or with type: Phaser.WEBGL set.  In your demo the DevTools, show the phaser banner twice, if you comment out the destructor in file _components/game/index.tsx , the phaser-banner is displayed once and the text looks correct. Sadly I don't know React/Next well enough, to narrow the issue down more. I added a Tag nextjs, since I think tweaking the next code could solve your issue.

@winner_joiner Thank you your advice helps me a lot. I wrote the destructor because, for React manner, useEffect callback must return function that clean up all stuffs modified in that callback. As you mentioned, I also have found that type: Phaser.WEBGL make it work well, and found it depends on environment: only in Chrome on PC. I am getting feeling that it is a bug in phaser library...

I updated my initial answer, with two solutions for using the normal text GameObject. I hope this solves your issue, and happy coding. :)

@winner_joiner Thank you for your help! I was stuck on this problem for several days and am almost giving up phaser framework. You helped me for real.

Update(2024-07-26) Two possible "Solutions":
I did some more digging, and found the solutions to the problem:

Since the problem has to do with some canvas cleanup issue, you could simply set the phaser "CanvasPool" to an empty list, in the destructor, before destroying the game object. This would force hte creation of new html-canvas objects
// ...
return () => {
  if (game.current) {
    Phaser.Display.Canvas.CanvasPool.pool = [];
    game.current.destroy(true);      

    if (game.current !== null) {
      game.current = null;
    }
  }
} //...


It seems that the double call of the useEffect has to do with running the app in development mode (StrictMode). If you start the application in production mode (npm run build and npm run start) phaser will not be start so fast in succession, so this error won't occur also. No other Changes needed (this info is base on this stackoverflow answer and short skimming the documentation)



I tested both options, with your MRE and both work fine.

This is a Phaser bases "Workaround" (Initial Answer)
you could use Phaser BitmapFonts. Since Bitmap Text GameObject is rendered/generated in a different way (not on an hidden internal canvas like the normal Text GameObject), so issue won't happen.
I tested your demo application with the bitmap font, and it works (on win11 chrome 126+).

Bitmap Text is not so flexible as the normal Text, but has better performance, they say. There are a few font conversion tools out there, that might help, if you need some special font, but since I never used one I can't suggest any. Also there are many Bitmap Fonts out there, ready to use (like here, or in the phaser bitmap-font examples, ...).


Thank you for your tough work and really detailed answer!

Your welcome, glad I could help. btw.: if you are once stuck with a phaser question, you can also checkout the official phaser forum some of the phaser - developers are pretty active there and helpful. In most cases you can get a answer in a few hours. (There is also an official phaser discord server, that is pretty active, but I never used it until now)
